# Android no recibe notificaciones push

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification

Al intentar recibir las notificaciones en `Android` se genera el siguiente error:

> Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
>  
>   Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.

El envío  lo he comprobado en la web http://techzog.com/development/gcm-notification-test-tool-android/ y se realiza correctamente pero no se recibe en el dispositivo.

`google-services.json` lo he situado en `/app`

Android Manifest:

```
<manifest package="com.packageName"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />  <!-- support previous 4.4 KitKat devices-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.packageName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<application
    android:name="AppName"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.packageName" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter> <!-- support previous 4.4 KitKat devices-->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.packageName" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.packageName.activities.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.packageName.activities.GcmIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.packageName.activities.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

MyGcmListenerService:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d("From", "From: " + from);
    Log.d("Msg", "Message: " + message);

  }

}
```

RegistrationIntentService:

```
 public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {
   private static String SENDER_ID = "MySenderID";

   public RegistrationIntentService(){
       super(SENDER_ID);
   }

   @Override
   public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){

      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

      try {
          InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
          String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
              GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
          Log.i("TOKEN", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.d("Fail token", "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
      }

  }


}
```

GcmIDListenerService:

```
public class GcmIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {
 @Override
 public void onTokenRefresh() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisando el código y el `Manifest.xml` encontré que te falta el permiso:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.packageName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

agregalo abajo de:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.packageName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Revisa el ejemplo de la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest), "ejemplo de manifest que soporta GCM":

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="<your-package-name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application ...>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.example.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.example.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Te puedo comentar que cuando implemente un ejemplo por primera ocasión eliminé ese permiso ya que consideré que estaba repetido =P, esto es una causa para que no recibas notificaciones.

Comment: He añadido el permiso pero aún así sigue generando el mismo error.